# How to upload flat file directly into ACDOCU table on SAP S/4 HANA On Premise 1809?

Tags: migration, s4hana

I am using SAP S/4 HANA Group Reporting On Premise 1809,

I need a solution for uploading legacy data from a flat-file (txt, csv) directly into the table ACDOCU.

Is there anybody with an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

SAP S/4HANA Migration Cockpit is the recommended tool for migrating legacy data to S/4HANA since S/4HANA 1511 and higher (see note [2287723](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2287723)).

It can be called via transaction code `LTMC` and requires role `SAP_CA_DMC_MC_USER`. Here is the detailed guide how to create migration project and use files for migration:

[Transferring Data to SAP S/4HANA Using Files](https://help.sap.com/viewer/29193bf0ebdd4583930b2176cb993268/1909.000/en-US/9bea452cfae3493eb1aee55d8dbaa07c.html)

It uses Excel XML files however it is quite easy to convert CSVs into XMLs. If you don't want to make conversion, [migration through staging tables](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/13/working-with-staging-tables-in-s4hana-migration-cockpit-onpremise/) can be an option for you, as HANA Studio allows uploads of CSV.

Another option is Data Integrator tool, which is in fact stripped-down version of SAP Data Services. It is provided free of charge to S/4HANA users and can be downloaded also from the above note.

However, for such simple case as flat file I recommend stick to Migration Cockpit. Read [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/29/migrating-data-to-your-new-sap-s4hana/) for more clarity about SAP migration strategy now.